# Freewheel for my hub

Tags: hub

I've got back wheel with shimano 5353 hub and want to change it for a wheel with Campganolo record hub. I wanna know if my freewheel will fit Campganolo hub, coz it's and old version of freewheels which shimano did to 80-s

Help plz...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chances are but the Shimano and Campagnolo hubs use ISO standard freewheel threads (1.375" x 24 tpi). If the Campagnolo hub has the older Italian thread standard (1.378" x 24 tpi), the freewheel will thread on as the thread sizes are so close.

See https://www.sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html

Comment: As I could hardly see on photo of the hub, it's written 1.370*24